# ngrok having issues starting - X509 certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: ngrok

I'm using ngrok 3.1.1 and trying to open up port 8000 so I can do some local testing. However, I keep running into some issues.

First off, I've downloaded and installed ngrok from the official site, and then added by authorisation token using:

> ngrok config add-authtoken blahblahblahcrazywordsmoustache

So far so good. Then, trying to open ngrok using:

> ngrok http 8000

Yields the following errors:

> reconnecting (x509: certificate signed by unknown authority)

Followed by:

> reconnecting (jsonHTTP.Lookup: No such host: tunnel.ngrok.com)

And...

> reconnecting (resolved tunnel.ngrok.com has no records)

The ngrok.yml looks like this:

```
root_cas: trusted
version: "2"
authtoken: ohlooksomelettersarenttheynice
```

Any idea what I can do? This is on a corporate network, with various firewalls etc. I'm told that ngrok will create a url that I can use in my code tests, but we can't whitelist that url until we know what it is, and we don't know what it is until ngrok starts and generates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, not quite a solution but more of a work-around.

Disconnected my computer from the corporate network, used a wifi dongle and hotspotted to my phone.

Got an error saying that my account wasn't authorised to use custom CAs. Wracked my head for a bit until I remembered that I had seen cas before, in the yml file. Removed the

> root_cas: trusted

from the yml, and all working fine and dandy.

Comment: where is this file?

Answer (score 6):

PM from ngrok here. Usually when I see those types of cert errors on a corporate network, it means there is some sort of corporate network security service blocking traffic to the url used by the ngrok agents to create a secure connection to the ngrok service.

This means your corporate IT is blocking usage of ngrok. You can use the `ngrok diagnose` command to see if it can provide you any additional details. That's explained in the [using ngrok inside corporate firewalls](https://ngrok.com/docs/guides/running-behind-firewalls/) guide.

ngrok has paid plans that allow enterprises to customize these agent ingress urls and control access.